# Compiler error with LLVM Xcode Version 4.6.1 (4H512)

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, clang, llvm-clang

Seeing this error when we recently upgrade Xcode to 4.6.1. Was able to compile perfectly prior to this version. Any insight into this message? Seems like a 32/64 bit issue?

From looking at [LLVM Patch logs](http://www.csl.cornell.edu/~fang/sw/llvm/patches/llvm-local-r175024b.patch) it appears that it's an unfortunate limitation of the MachO format.

```
fatal error: error in backend: Section too large, can't encode r_address (0x1000005) into 24 bits of scattered relocation entry.
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, I've set the LLVM compilation level to Fastest, Smallest [-Os].